# How to ignore control characters when execute read in bash

Tags: bash

To read a line into variable in bash, I run

```bash
read -p "here:" _msg; echo "${_msg}" > _read
```

With the expectation of `xyz123` for `_msg`, I made `123` first accidentally, now I need to hit <kbd>←</kbd> 3 times to move the cursor before `1`, after that continue to input `xyz`, but it seems just like entered <kbd>INSERT</kbd> mode, `123` was gone, there was only `xyz`

```
here:xyz
```

Then I checked the final file

```bash
xxd _read
```

I got

```
00000000: 7879 7a1b 5b44 1b5b 441b 5b44 3132 330a  xyz.[D.[D.[D123.
```

How to ignore the control characters for the input

I was running bash in MINGW64 on Windows

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using and what operating system? I have never seen a `read` prompt that supports moving backwards with the arrow key as you describe. Is this some inputtrc setting you have set up? Also, as a general rule, try to avoid prompting users for input, that just makes your code more complex, harder to reproduce and your program impossible to automate. Unless you absolutely _must_ do this, try using options or arguments instead.

Comment: @terdon my xterm in cygwin lets me use the backarrow keys as the OP describes but doesn't leave control characters behind.

Comment: Don't use the arrow key to delete chars from the end of the line, use the backspace key.

Comment: Or use Ctrl+U to delete everything you've typed so far

Comment: @terdon, the escape sequences that arraw keys send are usually those which when echoed back to the terminal move the cursor accordingly. If you're seeing things like `^[[A`, it would because the terminal device line discipline has the `echoctl` flag on in your case which transforms ESC to `^[` upon local echo. After `stty -echoctl` which disables that and causes all characters to be echoed as-is (except maybe for CR and the line editing ones) you should see arrow keys moving the cursor in `read`.

Comment: @EdMorton, actually I was not trying to delete anything, I was trying to move the cursor from the end to the beginning, rather than appending on tail I would like to insert at the head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for `bash` (`man bash`) and in particular the section describing `read` you'll see that there's an extra option:

> **`-e`** If the standard input is coming from a terminal, `readline` (see READLINE above) is used to obtain the line.

And above that, as directed:

> **READLINE** This is the library that handles reading input when using an interactive shell […]

Applying the instruction you then get this:

```
read -e -p "here:" _msg; printf '%s\n' "$_msg" > _read
```

After entering `123`, three cursor lefts, and `abc`, I get this from the file `_read`:

```
hexdump -C _read
00000000  61 62 63 31 32 33 0a                              |abc123.|
```

Comment: Note that with `-e`, `read` still does IFS and backslash processing, so you still need `IFS= read -rep 'here: ' _msg`. Also note that while with `-e` which uses `readline`, readline will let you enter newline characters with ^V^J like at the bash prompt, `read` will strip everything past it. See `zsh` and its `vared` variable editor builtin for a better way to input strings from the user with a line editor.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think that in this case, as it's reading user input, it's better to allow `read` to do its thing with whitespace. As Terdon points out, depending on the context it's often better to allow the user to supply args on the command line

Comment: I checked `man zshbuiltins` on `macOS`, It seems we do not have equivalent option for `zsh`, or did I miss something?

Comment: @http8086, as I said above, that's the `vared` builtin with zsh. See `info zsh vared`, though `info` is likely not installed by default on macos, but you can always [check online for vared in the latest version](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared).

Comment: Chris, why would it ever be fine for `read` or anything to mangle / transform the user's input without their knowledge? If I want to include backslash or space characters in the password I input, why would it be fine for `read` to strip them? I can understand `IFS=' ' read -p 'Enter words separated with space, backslash to escape them: ' -A array` to be useful but not `read a_single_string`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas there are use cases I can think of right now where squashing multiple spaces to a single space, and removing leading/trailing whitespace completely would not just be acceptable but necessary. If not in the input process then immediately afterwards as an explicit stage in processing